# How to create bounding boxes around the ROIs using keras

Tags: python, keras, convolution, bounding-box

I have to questions regarding `keras` and Convolutional Neural Networks:

1.
 How to create bounding boxes using `keras` and convolution neural network ?

2.
 How to use keras `vgg16` application retraining?

Comment: I am looking for the same!